# Waste of Screen visual studio code

Tags: gnome-shell, visual-studio-code

In Visual studio code, there is screen wastage.
Is there any solution to merge menubar and titlebar with the shell?

[image]

Answer (score 26):

There is a settings named `titleBarStyle`. Set it to `"custom"`. In `settings.json` it should be look like this:

```json
{
  "window.titleBarStyle": "custom"
}
```

---

If you don't want to edit `settings.json` manually, the "Title Bar Style" setting is in Settings → Window -- or just begin to type *title bar* in the "Search settings" text box and it will be found:

[image: screenshot of Settings in VS Code]

---

In either case, VS Code must be restarted to apply the change, and once the change has been applied, VS Code looks like this, with the title bar and menu bar merged into one:

[image: screenshot of VS Code with custom title bar]

Answer (score 6):

Go to File>Preference>Settings and in user settings write "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",

Answer (score 2):

I use mostly keyboard while developing. So, I just press <kbd>F11</kbd> and make VScode full screen. If you need to switch between browser/vscode, try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> to quickly switch. Other than that, there are some GNOME Shell extensions (e.g. [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/)) that do what you are asking for.