# Visual Studio Code UI is visually mismatched in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: themes, 19.10, visual-studio-code

The VS Code UI has been changed in 19.10 and it's not good as it was in 19.04 and earlier. The menu bar in VS Code deviates from the Ubuntu 19.10 system theme, and it has a disconcerting white background instead of being dark. The VS Code UI also deviates from the default system theme in a few other minor ways. This mismatched UI is annoying to someone who uses Visual Studio Code on a daily basis, and it's no longer possible to save slick looking screenshots of my code.

Is there any way to get a decent looking UI back in Visual Studio Code?

[image]

Comment: [Waste of Screen visual studio code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135953/waste-of-screen-visual-studio-code) may solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the Visual Studio Code snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```

or search for Visual Studio Code in the Ubuntu Software app.

In your screenshot I noticed that the terminal pane isn't open at the bottom of Visual Studio Code. Because Visual Studio Code can run code of many programming languages, I keep the terminal pane open all the time. To open the terminal pane from the Visual Studio Code menu select *Terminal* → *New Terminal*.

Explorer pane:

[image: Explorer pane in VS Code]

VS Code menu bar + breadcrumb navigation bar looks like the default Ubuntu Ambiance theme, which is not surprising because Visual Studio Code is packaged as an app in Ubuntu Software.

[image: VS Code menu bar]

Comment: do you also have white color on navigation?

Comment: @karel can you show me Header ( navigation ) of VSCode, please?

Comment: "The Visual Studio Code snap package still looks normal." this is no longer accurate

Answer (score 32):

Open your **settings.json** and add the following:

```
{
...
    "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
...
}
```

VS-Code will then prompt for a restart of the application. With GruvBox theme this was the result:

[image: vs-code screenshot]

Answer (score 14):

Open Settings and search for **Title Bar Style**. Changing that option to **custom** could possibly fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Selecting "custom" worked for me. I edited answer to add an image - no settings.json editing required